Batch upload files
I'm trying to batch upload files to Google Drive. I have all of my files uploaded on google drive and I want to copy them into all subfolders of a given parent folder. Currently when I execute this code it returns an error saying

TypeError :  folders.hasNext is not a function"

even though I followed documentation. I'm new to JavaScript and Google Apps Script
function File_uploader() {
  const file = "FILE ID"
  const parent_folder = "PARENT FOLDER ID"
  // Get all subfolders inside my parent folder
  var folders = DriveApp.getFolderById(parent_folder)
  //iterates through subfolders and pastes my file in them
  while (folders.hasNext()){
    folders.next()
    file.makeCopy
  }
}

ok so I think I understand where the problem comes from, when I execute this small bit of code:
function File_uploader() {
  const parent_folder_id = "FOLDER ID"
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(parent_folder_id)
  const subfolders = folder.getFolders
  Logger.log(subfolders)

the logger.log method returns me "function () { [nativecode] }" instead of "FolderIterator" which is why the .hasNext() method does not work.
I have no idea of why this happens as this code is the same as in this demo I found on YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CzxQsGKRgzE (timecode ~1'40)
It works! I had to use this code
 const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(parent_folder_id).GetFolders()

When done like this I do get a FolderIterator, thank you all

First, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. About So basically I'm trying to batch upload files to Google Drive., where are your files? From your showing script, do you want to just copy a file on Google Drive to a folder on Google Drive?

It looks like there is a misconception problem here:
DriveApp.getFolderById(...) returns a DriveApp.Folder object, so there is no need to use the DriveApp.FolderIterator.getNext() method. However, if you are looking to do something with the files in the folder, you should first get DriveApp.FileIterator object. For details please checkout the example on the reference page for this class -> https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file-iterator.
